# Screen Saver Setup

Tags: screensaver

What is the setup for screen saver and image choices in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? I cannot find anything in "setup" or "utilities." Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I don't know what the stock screensaver is, I always install `xscreensaver` and enjoy its wide selection of different interesting modes.

Comment: I "save" my screen by using Blank Screen option under Power in settings. A quick touch of Enter and the screen is restored. Perfect.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!